# Invalid Selector Argument 'Type=armor_stand'

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft Java Edition version 1.12.2, I attempted to execute:

```
/entitydata @e[Type=armor_stand,r=5] {Invisible:1}
```

This yielded an error:

> Invalid Selector Argument'Type=armor_stand'

What is wrong with the target selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `type` instead of `Type`. Entity selectors are case sensitive.